# What class does this variable belong to?

Tags: c#

```
class Program
{
    class Mammal
    {

    }

    class Horse : Mammal
    {

    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Horse myHorse = new Horse();
        Mammal myMammal = myHorse;
        Horse myHorseAgain = myMammal as Horse;
    }
}
```

Will `myHorseAgain` have methods defined in Horse class?

Comment: You are casting it as `Horse`, so the answer is yes.

Comment: Note that downcasting is not usually a good idea and is *definitely* a code smell

Comment: That variable belongs to me, as your soul....

Comment: Don't ask this question. **Run the code.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will. Although it is going through an upcast, you will find that for the upcasted (`Mammal`) instance, the following condition still holds:

```
(myMammal is Horse) == true
```

But actually doing this is an anti-pattern. Go for an architecture using [interfaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173156.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Two points here.

1º: It does not matter how many times you cast. If the compiler manages to turn Mammal into Horse again, then he will be a Horse, so he will have all of Horse's behaviors.

2nd: Stacking casts this way is definitely not a good practice.